# How do I sort a Pandas dataframe Excel import?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have imported the following Excel file but would like to sort it based on Frequency descending, but then with 'Other','No data' and 'All' (the total) at the bottom in that order. Is this possible?

```
table1 = pd.read_excel("table1.xlsx")
table1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'generalenq':list('abcdef'),
         'percentage':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'frequency':[5,3,6,9,2,4],

})

df.loc[0, 'generalenq'] = 'All'
df.loc[2, 'generalenq'] = 'No data'
df.loc[3, 'generalenq'] = 'Other'
print (df)
  generalenq  percentage  frequency
0        All           1          5
1          b           3          3
2    No data           5          6
3      Other           7          9
4          e           1          2
5          f           0          4
```

First create dictionary for ordering by some integers. Then create mask by membership with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and sorting non matched rows selected with `~` for invert mask with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
d = {'Other':0,'No data':1,'All':2}
mask = df['generalenq'].isin(list(d.keys()))

df1 = df[~mask].sort_values('frequency', ascending=False)
print (df1)
  generalenq  percentage  frequency
5          f           0          4
1          b           3          3
4          e           1          2
```

Then filter matched rows by mask and create helper column for sorting by mapped dict:

```
df2 = df[mask].assign(new = lambda x: x['generalenq'].map(d)).sort_values('new').drop('new', 1)
print (df2)
  generalenq  percentage  frequency
3      Other           7          9
2    No data           5          6
0        All           1          5
```

And last join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
  generalenq  percentage  frequency
0          f           0          4
1          b           3          3
2          e           1          2
3      Other           7          9
4    No data           5          6
5        All           1          5
```